# How I can get the return value of a decorator in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-decorators

I have the following function:

```
def check_if_commands_channel(ctx):                                            
    return str(ctx.message.channel.id) == constants.DISCORD_COMMANDS_CHANNEL_ID
```

I decorate this command with this function so this command will just answer in a specific channel id.

```
@client.command(name="hey")                                            
@commands.check(check_if_commands_channel)                              
async def hey(ctx):                                                    
    await ctx.channel.send("hey!")
```

But, I want the return value of the decorator inside the `hey()` function. How can I do that?

Comment: the return on this will be True or False. Is that what you want? You are checking for a condition. So the result will be a Boolean value and not what you think it should return

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231318/return-the-channel-id-of-a-channel-mentioned-in-a-command

Comment: The return boolean is just an example, instead I was thinking of return a string from the decorator function. The point is, I don't know if I'm can catch the return value of the decorator and use it inside the command function, that's what I want to do. What's this reference? Sorry man, but this isnt even about the languague that I'm talking about.

Comment: my bad @Caio, I shared the wrong link. I get your point though

Comment: That's ok, @Joe Ferndz. Did you know if I can do this? Probably I'm limited by my knowledge with decorators, tell me if this is a simple thing that I'm not seeing.